# .htaccess help within root and public

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a small mvc application where I'm trying to force the url to go from www.example.com to www.example.com/public.

In order to do this, I have a .htaccess file in the root (/) and then another .htaccess within the /public folder to point to index.php with friendly urls. I believe the issue is within the htaccess file that sits in the public folder, I need all requests to go through index.php

I have tried a few threads on stackoverflow but seems to give me a server 500 error when I access www.example.com

.htaccess of root

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /public/

</IfModule>
```

.htaccess of public folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}% !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}% !-d
    #allow images, css and js links
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|js|jpe?g|gif|png)$ [NC]


    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: DirectoryIndex yourindex.php

Comment: which part do I add that? Within the root or public .htaccess file?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteRule (.*) /public/index.php
```

Comment: thanks for the input Nathan, within this if I wanted www.example.com/about how would I add this ?